# Apply child value to parent key if specific key exists in child in object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

```
const obj = {
  uid: "893212",
  a: {name: "Down here!", uid: "1231"},
  b: {
    c: {uid: "5965"},
    name: "bud name",
  }, 
  d: {name: "doodle name"},
  e: {name: "alexa name"},
  f: ["kk", "jj"],
  g: [
   {
     h: {uid: "47895"},
     i: {uid: "4785"}
   },
   {
     j: {uid: "4895"}
   }
  ]
};
```

in the above object if "uid" exist its value should be applied to its parent as a value.
result should be as below

```
var result = {
  uid: "893212",
  a: "1231",
  b: {c: "5965", name: "bud name"},
  d: {name: "doodle name"},
  e: {name: "alexa name"},
  f: ["kk", "jj"],
  g: [
   {h: "47895", i: "4795"},
   {j: "4895"}
  ]
}
```

I tried to use recursive function to manipulate object.

```
const mapObj = (obj = {}) => {
  if (isObject(obj)) {
    const entries = Object.entries(obj);

    for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i += 1) {
      const [objK, objV] = entries[i];
      
      if (isObject(objV) && 'uid' in objV) {
        obj[objK] = objV['uid'];          
      } else if(isObject(objV)){
        findNestedObject(objV);
      } else if(isArray(objV)) {
        objV.forEach(val => {
          findNestedObject(val);
        })
      }
    } 
  }
};
```

is there any simple way to do it and array of objects are converted

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const obj = {
  uid: "893212",
  a: {name: "Down here!", uid: "1231"},
  b: {
    c: {uid: "5965"},
    name: "bud name",
  }, 
  d: {name: "doodle name"},
  e: {name: "alexa name"},
  f: ["kk", "jj"],
  g: [
   {
     h: {uid: "47895"},
     i: {uid: "4785"}
   },
   {
     j: {uid: "4895"}
   }
  ]
};

const process = (anObject) => {
  const toReturn = {};
  Object.keys(anObject).forEach((key, index) => {
    const currentProperty = anObject[key];  
    if(Array.isArray(currentProperty)) {  
      toReturn[key] = currentProperty;
    }
    else if(typeof(currentProperty) === 'object') {
      const uid = currentProperty?.uid;
      if(uid) {
        toReturn[key] = uid;
      } 
      else {
        toReturn[key] = process(currentProperty);
      }         
    } else {
      toReturn[key] = currentProperty;
    }
  });
  return toReturn;
}

const target = process(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(target, null, 2));
```